# Saving application logs to a text file does not work

Tags: android, logging

I want save my android application logs on a text file and send it via email in order to handling exceptions and feedback. I implemented following codes in my application, but logs text file contains nothing and is empty after executing code.

```
try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        StringBuilder logString = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            logString.append(line);
        }

        File logFile = new File("sdcard/log.txt");
        if (!logFile.exists()) {
            try {
                logFile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true));
        buf.append(logString);
        buf.newLine();
        buf.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I used `Log.i`, `Log.e` and `Log.w` for writing log messages to logcat in my whole application.

I would be grateful if anyone guide me to addressing my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try This,

```
public static void appendLog(String text) {
    if (true) {

        File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/YourAppName");
        dir.mkdir();
        File logFile = new File(dir, "YourAppName.txt");

        if (!logFile.exists()) {
            try {
                logFile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            // BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file
            // flag
            BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile,
                    true));
            buf.append(text
                    + " - "
                    + new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
                            .format(new Date()));
            buf.newLine();
            buf.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and Used this method instead of `Log.i`, `Log.e` and `Log.w` in your application

Comment: try to explain the changes too so that other people checking your answer later on can understand too

Comment: I don't understand why you use `Process` for append log? it's actually when you use `BufferedWriter` it Wraps an existing Writer and buffers the output. so no need to use `Process` and other methods. just get file and write(append) your log on previous log.

Comment: @AbhishekPatel Thanks for your quick answer. I used Process for accessing system logs. According to your answer, I would not able to track not handled exceptions and even crashes. Only appended logs could be monitored.